# How to remove the "Close comment thread" button in Open Atrium?

Tags: 6, theming, distributions

On my casetracker nodes in Open Atrium, the `atrium.module` inserts a "Close comment thread" / "Reopen comment thread" button.  What's the simplest way to remove this button, without having to modify `atrium.module`?

Comment: I haven't used OA much yet, but isn't there a user permission that decides if a user is allowed to open/close a comment thread? In that case, setting the correct permissions should hide the button when the user isn't allowed to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at atrium.module, specifically function atrium_preprocess_node(), shows that the "Close comment thread" is only shown when the user has the right to update the node (`node_access('update', $vars['node'])` returns `true`). That means that you can hide the button by taking away that permission.

Alternatively, you could implement hook_form_alter in a custom module and set $form to an empty array when $form_id equals 'atrium_comment_thread_toggleform, or (but this may be tricky) implement `THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$vars)` in your theme's template.php and alter $vars['post_object'] to take out the form again.

Comment: I'd like to retain users' ability to edit nodes.  But `hook_form_alter()` sounds like a reasonable solution.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me: `function mymodule_form_atrium_comment_thread_toggleform_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { $form = array(); }`